# Enabling MFA to JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, devops

I am looking for enabling MFA to our Jenkins .I haven't found any plugin or procees to enable 2FA .Please anybody suggest any plugin or process (preferred open source)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't implement advanced security features like MFA just with Jenkins. The recommendation is to either use OIDC or SAML with SSO(Single Sign On) and implement MFA in the IDP(Identity Provider) itself. If you don't have an in-house IDP you can use Google, Facebook, or any other Opensource IDP.

OIDC - https://plugins.jenkins.io/oic-auth/
SAML - https://plugins.jenkins.io/saml/